# I want to increase a minimum figure by 5 every 60 secs and must not exceed maximum figure in Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I'm working on a project where I'm displaying two amounts. The first one is the minimum amount which is constant. However, the second one is the progress (increment) every 60 seconds but the figure must not exceed the maximum amount set within a certain duration.
an example is:
I have a min amount of 10,000.
max amount = 50,000.
savings duration= 93 days.
now, I want the progress count (a label showing how the savings is growing) to keep increasing by a certain given time (probably 60 seconds) until the 93rd day without exceeding the maximum amount.

My question is, how do I achieve this? what method can best give a good result?

Here is my current implementation:

```
public string TotalBalance
    {
        get
        {
            //string newBal;
            double min;
            double max;
            double dys;
            dys = double.Parse(days);
            double calc = dys * 1440;
            min = double.Parse(amount);
            max = double.Parse(totalReturn);
            double costpermin = max / calc;
            if (dys>0)
            {
                string kems;
                Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60), () =>
                {
                    // do something every 60 seconds
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        double pel = min + costpermin++;
                        string polo = pel.ToString();
                        string Bal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(polo), 2).ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")).Replace("$", "N");

                        kems = Bal;
                        var updAmt = Bal;
                        MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "timer", updAmt);
                    });
                    return true; // runs again, or false to stop
                });
                return kems;
            }
            else
            {
                string meeBal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(this.totalReturn), 2).ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")).Replace("$", "N");
                return meeBal;
            }
        }

        set
        {
            TotalBalance = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalBalance));
        }
    }
```

I added deviceTimer in my model to be able to update the view real-time. however, there are some issues. 1. the calculation is right but only calculates after the first 60secs. so onAppearance, the amount label shows empty. and the view doesn't get updated still. 2. the calculation doesn't continue tomorrow, so if today your total growth shows 10,200.12, when you open the app again tomorrow, it will start the counting again instead of starting from where it started.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I added deviceTimer in my model to be able to update the view real-time. however, there are some issues.
1. the calculation is right but only calculates after the first 60secs. so onAppearance, the amount label shows empty. and the view doesn't get updated still.
2. the calculation doesn't continue tomorrow, so if today your total growth shows 10,200.12, when you open the app again tomorrow, it will start the counting again instead of starting from where it started.

Comment: I've updated my question. please take a look again

Comment: every time your timer fires, increase the amount.  If the amount exceeds the maximum value, stop the timer.

Comment: If you want it to start tomorrow where it stopped today, you'll need to store the current amount somewhere when your app stops running.  Does Xamarin have `IsolatedStorage` - that's a good place?  If you want it show a value that would make it look like it had continued while it was stop, save the value and a timestamp and do a little calculation when you start up.

Answer (score 1):

try using Device.StartTimer() to increment count periodically

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms